# ELSE stmt is executed even if IF stmt was executed in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following piece of code which contains if-else statement. when I print it it looks like the else part is been executed even though the if part is executed as well. I ran it with cat -A and the indentation looks fine

```
print "PRINT os.fork"
pid = os.fork()
if pid:
    print "PRINT IF %d" %pid
    os.close(write_fd)
    self.pid2file[pid] = read_fd
else:
    print "PRINT ELSE"
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, signal.SIG_DFL)$
```

Here is the output:

```
PRINT os.fork
PRINT IF 63185
PRINT ELSE
```

btw, all the code reside inside a loop.

I appreciate any ideas for this behavior...

Comment: You use fork() there. So there will be two processes: one with a pid=0 (the child) and one with pid=something (the parent). The parent will enter the if branch, the child the else.

Answer (score 3):

That's because with `os.fork()` you are creating a new child process. Execution of *both* processes, the existing parent and the new child, continues from the line following the `os.fork()`.

The PID of the child is available in the parent as the return value from `os.fork()`, so it executes the `if` part.

In the child, the PID is 0 which causes the `else` part to be executed,

Both processes, parent and child, produce output on stdout which is displayed in your terminal.

So it not the case that *both* the `if` and `else` statements are executed in the one process; one is executed by the parent process (when a non-zero PID is returned), and the other is executed by the child process when the PID is zero.

Answer (score 0):

You have two processes: the original one (the parent) and the new one that you create with fork, since the two processes write into the same output then you will experience interference of the outputs: the PRINT IF in the parent process and the PRNT else in the child process.
you can fix this by attributing different outputs (e.g 2 different text files) for each process

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies!